# SetIpInterfaceEntry returns ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to execute [SetIpInterfaceEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/netioapi/nf-netioapi-setipinterfaceentry) function, but I'm always getting `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` result. It isn't important which exact parameter I wanted to change because I'm getting this error even if I don't change anything. Here's C++ code sample which doesn't change anything, yet the output is always the same:

```
// Initialize MIB_IPINTERFACE_ROW with actual InterfaceLuid:
auto row = MIB_IPINTERFACE_ROW{ AF_INET, 1689399632855040 };

auto result = GetIpInterfaceEntry(&row);

// Just to confirm GetIpInterfaceEntry success print result and InterfaceIndex:
std::cout << "GetIpInterfaceEntry result: " << result << "; InterfaceIndex: " << row.InterfaceIndex << std::endl;

// Try to execute SetIpInterfaceEntry, without any change:
result = SetIpInterfaceEntry(&row);

// Result is always ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER (87):
std::cout << "SetIpInterfaceEntry result: " << result << std::endl;
```

Here's the output of the previous snippet:

```
GetIpInterfaceEntry result: 0; InterfaceIndex: 13
SetIpInterfaceEntry result: 87
```

According to [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/netioapi/nf-netioapi-setipinterfaceentry), possible reasons for `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` are:

> An invalid parameter was passed to the function. This error is returned if a `NULL` pointer is passed in the Row parameter, the Family member of the `MIB_IPINTERFACE_ROW` pointed to by the Row parameter was not specified as `AF_INET` or `AF_INET6`, or both the `InterfaceLuid` or `InterfaceIndex` members of the `MIB_IPINTERFACE_ROW` pointed to by the Row parameter were unspecified.

Neither of which can be true in my case (I've just got the actual struct).

My question is obvious: what I'm doing wrong? Are there any restrictions on which kind of interface the method can be called? (I'm calling on physical one.) Any other suggestion?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: I've forgot to mention that, if you want to execute this code snippet you should:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <netioapi.h>
```

And also link `iphlpapi.lib`.

Comment: What happened if `row.Family` is specified as `AF_INET6`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it with your code, `SetIpInterfaceEntry ` did just succeed(return 0) on win10,1809, build 17763. Could you provide your environment info?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, thanks to my colleague...

The cause was in the fact that in my case `row.SitePrefixLength` field was originally set to `64`, which is an illegal value, according to [MIB_IPINTERFACE_ROW doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/netioapi/ns-netioapi-_mib_ipinterface_row):

> For an IPv4 address, any value greater than 32 is an illegal value.

As soon as I inserted the following line before [SetIpInterfaceEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/netioapi/nf-netioapi-setipinterfaceentry) call, everything went OK:

```
row.SitePrefixLength = 0;
```

Although it solved the problem, there are still few open questions:

1. How it happened that actual current value is invalid?
2. What value to put if you encounter an invalid value there? It looks that setting it to `0` is the answer, but I'm not sure about that.

But in the first place I should probably find out what's the purpose of `SitePrefixLength` field/param. :)

**UPDATE**: I've just found the answer for my second remaining question - it was in [the same doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/netioapi/nf-netioapi-setipinterfaceentry) all the time (shame on me for not reading everything). So the answer is:

> For IPv4, the `SitePrefixLength` member must be set to 0.